# Параметры шаблона класса с конструктором в который передаются параметры

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, конструктор

Есть шаблон класса:

```
template <class T>
struct DtaStr_t
{
    T Par_1,Par_2,Par_3;
};
```

И есть класс c явным конструктором:

```
struct Sig_t
{
    float Coef_A;
    float Coef_B;
    Sig_t( float _Coef_B, float Coef_C )
    {
        Coef_B = _Coef_B;
        Coef_A = _Coef_B * Coef_C;
    }
};
```

Как при объявлении задать параметры конструктора?

```
DtaStr_t<Sig_t>* p = new DtaStr_t<Sig_t>; // так неправильно, нет параметров конструктора
```

Answer (score 1):

Параметры конструктора для класса `Sig_t` могут быть переданы конструктору шаблона класса, но таковой на данный момент у Вас отсутствует. Очевидно, шаблон класса может быть параметризирован любым типом, соответственно, было бы неправильным определить его следующим образом:

```
template<typename T>
class DtaStr_t
{
public:
    DtaStr_t(float, float) { /* impl */ }
};
```

, ведь как только в качестве параметра шаблона класса будет использован тип, отличный от `Sig_t`, этот конструктор окажется бесполезен.

Тогда у Вас есть два варианта:

1. Каждый раз реализовывать специализацию шаблона класса. В ней определять конструктор с подходящими аргументами. Этот вариант имеет право на существование, но я уверен, что в данном случае использовать его - бессмысленно.
2. Использовать *variadic template*:

```
template<typename T>
class DtaStr_t
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    DtaStr_t(Args&&... args)
        : Par_1(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
};
```

Пример:

```
auto ptr = new DtaStr_t<Sig_t>(10.1, 20.2);
```

Замечание: очевидно, что параметры, переданные как rvalue-значения, не могут быть переиспользованы, т.е., после того, как они были переданы конструктору члена Par_1, их уже нельзя передавать конструктору Par_2 и т.д. Здесь Вы сами должны определить, как Вы их будете передавать (например, по ссылке).

Answer (score 0):

Для `Sig_t` создайте конструктор по умолчанию:

```
Sig_t() : Coef_A(), Coef_B() {}
```

Или же можно использовать список инициализации из С++11:

```
Sig_t A(1, 2);
Sig_t B(3, 4);
Sig_t C(5, 6);
DtaStr_t<Sig_t>* p = new DtaStr_t<Sig_t>{A, B, C};
```